# How to come up with this error estimation?

Tags: distributions, self-study, estimation

I am trying to understand the answer to [question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223351/trajectory-estimation) of a [trajectory estimation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1osqHVYJyDpHnOKQH7wfJQ7qfubwdfHEd).

The vertical coordinate (“height") of an object in free fall is described by an equation of the form
$x(t) = \theta _0 + \theta _1t + \theta _2 t^2,$

We assume that $\theta_0$ is a known constant. We also assume that $\theta_2$ is known. We view $\theta_1$ as the realized value of a continuous random variable $\Theta _1$.

In this case, finding the MAP estimate of $\Theta _1$ involves the minimization of
$$\theta _1^2+ \frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\sum _{i=1}^ n(y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _1 t_ i -\theta _2 t_ i^2)^2$$
with respect to $\theta_1$.

1)$$\hat{\theta }_1 = \frac{\sum ^ n_{i=1}t_ i(y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _2t^2_ i)}{\sigma ^2+\sum _{i=1}^ n t_ i^2}$$

2) Let $\sigma =1$, and consider the special case of only two observations ($n=2$). Write down a formula for the mean squared error ${\bf E}[(\hat\Theta _1-\Theta _1)^2]$

---

Here in 2, it is stated that:

$${\bf E}[(\hat\Theta _1-\Theta _1)^2] = {\bf E}[(\hat\theta _1-\Theta _1)^2] = var(\Theta)$$

For a normal distribution, we recognize that the variance is determined by the coefficient that comes next to a term of the form $\theta _1^2$. So what we're looking for is the constant that sits next to the $\theta _1^2$ term. We collect all of them, it is $1/2*(1+t _1^2+t_2^2)$. So the final answer is
$$1/(1+t_1^2+t_2^2)$$

---

I don't quite follow and understand what he is saying.  Can someone please clarify?  Thank you.

---

According to this paper on [trajectory estimation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1osqHVYJyDpHnOKQH7wfJQ7qfubwdfHEd), $\Theta = (\Theta_0, \Theta_1, \Theta_2)$, as can be seen here:

[image: img]

I don't quite follow and understand what he is saying.  Can someone please clarify?  Thank you.

Comment: After "it is stated that," the formula is mysterious because it equates an expectation involving *two* random variables $\hat\Theta_1$ and $\Theta$ (it's not a variance!) to the variance of an *undefined* random variable $\Theta.$  Perhaps the first step to take would be to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: @whuber, I have edited the question with more details from the paper on [trajectory estimation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1osqHVYJyDpHnOKQH7wfJQ7qfubwdfHEd).  Does it help?

Comment: @whuber, I still haven't got the answer to this question.  The other question is unrelated.  If you believe the other question can solve this, can you explain to me?  Thanks.

Comment: The apparent duplicate concerns computing an expectation.  This question falls apart at a point where it seems to misquote the duplicate and gives a nonsensical, undefined equation: that needs fixing or some explanation.

Comment: The linked question provided an ambiguous solution, and I am trying to find the detailed answer myself.  Can you undelete so others may help solving it?  I have provided all the details I know.